# The computation in "int64var = int32var * int32var" does not overflow as expected. Why?

Tags: gcc, posix, clock, integer-overflow, icc

I strongly believe that there is something strange going on, so I want to pose this question.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// shall return a monotonically increasing time in microseconds
int64_t getMonotonicTime() {
   struct timespec ts;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

   int64_t ret;
   ret = ts.tv_sec * 1000000; // #1 HERE
   ret += ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
   return ret;
}
```

The problematic line is `ts.tv_sec * 1000000` which causes an overflow on systems where `time_t` and `int` are 32bits large (which happens to be the case on my system), every time that `ts.tv_sec` is greater than  2 147 .

When I wrote testcases for this bug, I found that the Intel `icc` compiler did not overflow, even though I assured that its `time_t` is in fact also `32` bit wide and even if I disabled optimzations. The GCC behavior did cause overflow as expected.

Beyond undefined behavior, what could be the reason that intel does not overflow? What could be the rationale of the intel developers? Or is it simply a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: Perhaps seeing generated assembly would be helpful.

Comment: @zch i haven't got access to the machine currently, unfortunately.

Comment: @nos i used `sizeof` and it returns `4`. I can see that perhaps in assembly code, to avoid using another register, it first loads `tv_sec` into the register that holds also `ret` and then it naturally ends up with multiplying on 64bits. But why wouldn't gcc do so aswell if that's the better approach?

Comment: Fair enough. It could be interresting to see the assembly in the optimized and non optimzied cases. It could be a pure accident - the value just happened to be loaded into a 64 bit register. Does it look different if you just return 1 instead of the result ? (Edit, return 1 will probably just optimize it out, so some other trick had to be employed..)

Comment: `sizeof` returning `4` only means it's 32 bits if `CHAR_BIT` is `8` (which it probably is)

Comment: @DavidConrad i'm using POSIX, so that's guaranteed

Comment: @DavidConrad Come on, he mentioned he's running this code on an actual machine, let's not obsess about language-lawyer issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at this simple code:

```
long f(int a,int b){
  return a*b;
}
```

We see 3 different asm generated by gcc:

```
movl    %edi, %eax
imull   %esi, %eax
cltq
```

clang:

```
imull   %esi, %edi
movslq  %edi, %rax
```

intel:

```
movslq    %esi, %rsi
movslq    %edi, %rdi
imulq     %rsi, %rdi
movq      %rdi, %rax
```

Basically, you can multiply 2 32-bit numbers (`imull`) then sign-extend the result. Or you can sign-extend the operands then multiply them as 64-bit numbers (`imulq`), then you should in principle keep only the low 32 bits and sign-extend them, but that's unnecessary because the cases where that matters are those where there was an overflow (undefined behavior), and this optimization (removing the final sign-extension) is precisely what you observed.

Comment: I have no idea about x86 assembler instructions. What's the best assembly code in those three snippets? It looks more costly to me to do two sign extension moves instead of only one.

Comment: There is no obvious answer to "what is best", you would need to measure on your machine. Probably in this case the clang version is faster. But once you inline this function, in the middle of many computations, converting everything to the same size and sticking to it can be preferable. IIRC, on recent x86, it is often faster to convert to 32 bits than to use the 16-bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a signed integer overflow in C is undefined, so anything might happen.  It is likely on a 64-bit machine that the compiler will choose to use 64-bit registers to hold 32-bit values and so do a 64-bit machine multiply for this.  On the other hand, on a different machine or with a different compiler, it might use 32-bit registers and a 32-bit multiply.

If you want defined overflow behavior in C, you need to use *unsigned* types.  If you use

```
ret = (unsigned)ts.tv_sec * 1000000U;
```

you'll get well-defined behavior that wraps if `unsigned` is 32 bits.

Comment: It's important to note that multiplication of unsigned types like `uint16_t` (or even `uint32_t`) which might be smaller than `int` may not yield defined values--even in the lower bits--if they get promoted to a signed integer type before the multiplication.

Comment: @supercat: `unsigned` is guaranteed to be the same size as `int`, so no promotion will occur.

Comment: Although `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be the same size as `int`, many coding standards eschew it in favor of types like `uint32_t`, which could be larger or smaller than `int`.  If `int` is 33-65 bits, then `uint32_t` values must be manually cast to an unsigned value at least as big as `unsigned`, or a signed value at least 65 bits, before multiplication.  If `int` is smaller than 32 bits, the cast won't be necessary, but a cast to `unsigned` added for systems where it was necessary (which would be optimal on systems with larger `int` types) would fail.